# Filtering out random rows in a table by using the sum function

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an expense table designed using sqlite I would like to construct a query to filter out some random rows using the sum function on the amount column of the table.

Sample `Expense` table

```
Clients          Amounts
A                  1000
B                  3000
C                  5000
D                  2000
E                  6000
```

Assuming i would like total sum in the table above to be 10,000 i would like to construct a query which would return  any number of randoms rows that would add up to 10,000

So far i tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM Expense Table 
GROUP BY (Clients) 
HAVING SUM(AMOUNT)=10000
```

but i got nothing generated

I have also had a go with the random function but i'm assuming i need to specify a LIMIT

Comment: What baffles you? You group by `Clients`. So you should get `SUM` by `Clients` that is 10,000. You have none.

Comment: What is your desired output with your sample data above?  BCD = 10000 and ABE = 10000.

Comment: I would just like a random output of rows that summed up to 10000 so either one of them

Answer (score 0):

SQLLite does not support CTEs (specifically recursive ones), so I can't think of an easy way of doing this.  Perhaps you would be better off doing this in your presentation logic.

One option via SQL would be to string to together a number of `UNION` statements.  Using your above sample data, you would need to string 3 `UNIONs` to get your results:

```
select clients
from expense
where amounts = 10000
union 
select e.clients || e2.clients
from expense e
   inner join expense e2 on e2.rowid > e.rowid
where e.amounts + e2.amounts = 10000 
union 
select e.clients || e2.clients || e3.clients
from expense e
   inner join expense e2 on e2.rowid > e.rowid
   inner join expense e3 on e3.rowid > e2.rowid
where e.amounts + e2.amounts + e3.amounts = 10000
```

Resulting in ABE and BCD.  This would work for any group of clients, 1 to 3, whose sum is 10000.  You could string more unions to get more clients -- this is just an example.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f3b92/1)

(Here's a sample with up to 4 clients - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b01cf/2).

You can probably use dynamic sql to construct your endless query if needed, however, I do think this is better suited on the presentation side.

Comment: That looks like a really complex solution but it does look better than anything i have thought up. Is there any way i can return just one of those results at random ?

Comment: @BennOgidan -- depends on the version of sqllite you are using.  try this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f3b92/1) -- click cancel to use sql.js editor.

Comment: Thanks for this it is much closer but the format i would like them returned would be in a row by row format instead of a union so               **Clients B 3000, Client C 5000, Client D 2000**

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) (in your case, the value is equal to the weight).

This can be solved in SQL (see sgeddes's answer), but due to SQL's set-oriented design, the computation is rather complex and very slow.

You would be better off by reading the amounts into your program and solving the problem there (see [the pseudocode on the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem)).